# View the code inside a dll file

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, vb6

My current project was originally written in VB6. Later, we have converted this to .NET (VB).

The conversion process was as follows -

1. Just open the VB6 Solution file in VS 2012.
2. VS 2012 does some auto conversion.
3. Change the .net framework in project settings to 4.0

I don't know if this conversion was the right way to do. But, for us the project ran successfully even after changing to .NET 4.0 Framework with out any issues.

The current Problem is that I have a method called **getInfo()** which has been defined inside the dll file called **groupInfo.dll**. This method is not working properly and needs to be changed. For this, I need to know what is the code inside the DLL or even how to see the code in DLL file, replicate the same in another VB File and create a new DLL file from this and use it.

After reading few posts from this website, I tried to use the softwares called dotpeek (http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and .NET Reflected 8.3. Both of these softwares are not able to open my DLL file and I assume the problem could be it may not be a .NET DLL at all.

Can any one please help me to see the contents of code inside this DLL?
[image: Using dot peek]

[image: Using .NET Reflector]

[image: The way the method declared inside the code]

Comment: The last screenshots says the method is located in the "RefProp.dll" library? Are you sure you are looking in the right .DLL?

Comment: Refprop.dll is a copy of groupinfo.dll

Comment: NET reflector is indicating it is not a .NET assembly.  Is it something from the original VB6 project?

Comment: Yes, this was already present in old VB6 project and has been copied to new .NET automatically by VS auto conversion

Comment: Andrew Barber - How is this off-topic, I am NOT asking what tool to use here. I said I have tried using these tools, but they are of not much use to me.

Comment: Describe problem - Need to see the code inside this dll 2) What has been done so far - Is I tried to decompile using the two tools as shown above.

Comment: I think you are still using the old VB6 DLL.  None of the VB6 projects I have converted were all **that** automatic.  Look in the BIN folders of the converted project.

Answer (score 0):

use "Detect it easy" program to view the information of DLL. It will show you the information about the language used to create that DLL. after you see in what language the DLL is made, find an appropriate decompiler for that language.